# Converting JRuby RubyHash to Java Map?

Tags: java, ruby, scala, data-structures, jruby

I want to use JRuby to run some ruby scripts, get a result and continue using Java/Scala. Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert an object from a RubyHash to a Java or Scala Map.

Is there a simple way to do this?
Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Due to documentation it is `java.util.Map` so you can use either `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` or implicite ones `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` to covenrt to scala collections

Answer (score 0):

`class org.jruby.RubyHash implements java.util.Map`, so, it already *is* a Java `Map`, albeit a non-generic "raw" type.

Unfortunately, JRuby's `Hash` class only inherits the generic `to_java` method from `Kernel`, unlike `Array` which has its own version.

This works:

```
[1, 2, 3].to_java(:int)
```

This doesn't, although it looks like it should:

```
{ 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2 }.to_java(:string, :int)
```

[It might be worthwhile filing this as a feature request.]

Comment: Appreciate the answer, however, I am looking into something that wouldn't require me to change any existing ruby code.

Comment: You don't have to change anything. JRuby's `RubyHash` implements `java.util.Map`, therefore every Ruby `Hash` already *is* a Java `Map`. Now, if you want to have a *typed* *generic* `Map<K, V>`, then you *will* have to do *something*, because with Ruby being dynamically typed, there is simply nothing JRuby can do about statically providing a more precise type than a raw `Map` (or alternatively a `Map<Object, Object>`, which is more or less the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

`org.jruby.RubyHash` implements `java.util.Map` in a way that it attempts to convert Ruby objects to Java with "normal" Map operations.

e.g. if you have a hash such as: `{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }` which (internally) means you have `RubyString` keys mapped to `RubyFixnum` values in a hash instance, on the Java side `hash.get("a")` will work fine and return `1` as a `java.lang.Long`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change your approach slightly: this would involve only changing the way you initialize objects in ruby, the rest should be transparent.

Instead of using pure Ruby hash objects (`o=Hash.new` or `o={}`), please use instead **java.util.HashMap** like in this snippet:

```
require 'java'
o = java.util.HashMap.new # you could also use o = Java::JavaUtil::HashMap.new
```

From then on, `o` would be a java object used as a hash by Ruby code, and can still be accessed using java methods.

Another mode complete snippet:

```
>> require 'java'
=> true
>> o = Java::JavaUtil::HashMap.new
=> {}
>> o[1] = 2
=> 2
>> o["cm"] = true
=> true
>> p o.keys # ruby methods/interface
[1, "cm"]
=> nil
>> p o.keySet().to_a # java methods
[1, "cm"]
=> nil
```